# Chart and Text in InfoWindow

Tags: javascript, google-maps, infowindow

I am trying to put a chart which is dynamically created from google's `corechart` library and some text inside a markers `infoWindow`, ideally next to each other such that both can be seen nicely when opening a markers window. Is this possible? My current approach shows only the text and [object Object] for the graph, however when I set the content to just `node`, it does show the chart:

```
        var node        = document.createElement('div'),
            infoWindow  = new google.maps.InfoWindow(),
            chart       = new google.visualization.PieChart(node);

        chart.draw(data, options);

        var infoDetails = 
            '<p><b>Station Name</b>: ' + station.Name +
            '<br><b>Station ID</b>: ' + station._id +
            node
            '</p>';

        infoWindow.setContent(infoDetails);
```

What is a good practice to accomplish this?

Comment: Your current approach only adds a String representation of your node. Of course, setting content to 'node' only is the correct approach.

Comment: @dev8080 OK, but what about the `infoDetails`? I want to have both the chart and those details in the window.

Comment: Depends on howPiechart modifies 'node'...you have to create a div that contains both, same as you would in a normal html flow, and set it to infowindow's content. So, probably create a parent div which has the chart node as a child along with your text and other stuff.

Comment: If you could create a fiddle, it would be easy to demo.